# Text controls that allows increasing/decreasing of all texts font size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive

I am working on a freelancing project and I need to get this part done no matter what.

For screen resolutions lower than 1200px, I have used "rem" for font-size and changed the HTML font-size by using:

```
    curr_size = parseInt($("html").css("font-size"));
    curr_size = (curr_size * 100) /16;
    if(curr_size < 72.5) {
        curr_size += 2.5;
        $('html').css('font-size', ''+curr_size+'%');
    }
```

Coming to screen resolution > 1200px, I have converted everything to vw to support all browser zoom levels and big monitors.

All my font-size class starts with "fz-" and I am using this function below to change the font-size of all elements:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[class*=fz-]");
for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {

    var cursize  = parseInt($(elements).eq(index).css("font-size"));
    
    cursize = (cursize/15);
    var add = cursize + 0.05;
    $(elements).eq(index).css("font-size","calc("+add+"vw");        
}
```

This is working perfectly on 100% browser zoom, but when zoomed out and applied (or if the browser was by default at 50%), the text sizes in increasing humongously.

Any solutions that come to mind?

- N.B: I need to keep support for VW, and for browser zoom on all levels.

Comment: Can you further explain why the `vw` kicks in instead of just using `rem` the whole time? It just seems like the `rem` solution makes your whole problem much easier to manage as you can just swap your root font size to `vw` and keep all your ratios in check.

Comment: I have set the html font-size to 62.5% and used rem at first which was optimal for my case and easy to manipulate text enlargement feature.
But in order to support browser zoom out and very large screens, I had to overwrite my font size classes and switching to vw instead, so you won't feel any difference if the browser zoom level was 100% or 25%

Comment: doesn't setting your html font-size to a vw value have the same effect without needing to fiddle with all of your classes?

Comment: I actually might work when removing the overriding font size values, let me try it and get back to this discussion.
You might have solved my whole problem with the simplest way possible

Comment: @CallumMorrisson 
responsiveness for browser zoom out/in worked perfectly by setting the HTML font-size to 0.65vw instead of 62.5%.
And I have reached this so far for text enlargment:

    `
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        if(i ==0 ){
            curr_size = 0.65;
            curr_size += 0.04;
            $('html').css('font-size', ''+curr_size+'vw');
        }
       else{
            curr_size += 0.04;
            $('html').css('font-size', ''+curr_size+'vw');
       }
    } 
`

This is my code for this stage, am I aproaching it right?

Comment: I am limiting the increase by 3 clicks only, taking the first value as predefined, 2nd and 3rd value from the updated one.